# Let $f(x,y)=\frac{x^3-y^3}{x^2+y^2}$. Is f differentiable in $(0,0)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let 
$$f(x,y)=\frac{x^3-y^3}{x^2+y^2}$$

My solution manual says that this function is not diffb. in $(0,0)$ because it is not linear. Well my problem is that I don't see why this function is linear, and I also don't see why that would imply that $f$ is not differentiable.

Comment: Not sure about differentiability, but it's clear that $f$ is a linear function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ if we define $f(0, 0) = 0$.  Just compare $f(kx, ky)$ to $f(x, y)$.

Comment: @HewWolff: How the homogeneity of $f(x,y)$ could help the OP?

Comment: @Babak: heck, I don't know, but they did ask about it.

Comment: @HewWolff The function is not linear, just homogeneous of degree $1$.

Answer (score 5):

We find the directional derivatives at $(0,0)$. Assume $\Vert v\Vert =1$. Then

$$f'((0,0);v)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f((0,0)+h\cdot v)-f(0,0)}{h}$$

I take $f(0,0)=0$ to ensure continuity.

$$f'((0,0);v)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(hv_1,hv_2)}{h}$$

$$f'((0,0);v)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h^3v_1^3-h^3v_2^3}{h^3}\frac{1}{\Vert v\Vert}$$

$$f'((0,0);v)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h^3v_1^3-h^3v_2^3}{h^3} $$

$$f'((0,0);v)=v_1^3-v_2^3$$

Since the directional derivatives do not follow a linear dependence on $(v_1,v_2)$, we conclude $f$ cannot be differentiable at $(0,0)$.